# Proper way to catch resize events for a pane in GoldenLayout

Tags: javascript, layout, golden-layout

I want to taken an action in one pane (i.e. a container content item) when a resize event occurs (whether resizing the panes, the whole browser, or zoom). The below works, but... if I then drag around the panes, even go from left-right, to right-left, or top-bottom, it stops working.

I'm assuming re-arranging panes resets something, and there is a *proper* way to get a persistent event handler. But I cannot work it out from the docs.

```
myLayout.on('initialised',initPanes);

function initPanes(){
myLayout.root.contentItems[0].contentItems[0].on('resize',function(){
    console.log("First pane resized");  //TEMP
    });
myLayout.root.contentItems[0].contentItems[1].on('resize',function(){
    console.log("Second pane resized");  //TEMP
    });
//...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you bind your `resize` handler to some intermediate layout object, like `stack` or `column`, and these might be destroyed and re-created when you re-arrange the layout, killing your listener in the process.

You can check the object type like that:

```
%myLayout.root.contentItems[0].contentItems[0].type
"stack"
```

You should bind your "resize" listener to the Component's container instead:

```
myLayout.on('componentCreated',function(component) {
    component.container.on('resize',function() {
        console.log('component.resize',component.componentName);
    });
});
```

to prevent it from being removed when you re-arrange the layout.

Answer (score 2):

With GoldenLayout, if you want to generically detect anytime some panel is moved or resized, the stateChanged property captures changes to the layout:

```
myLayout.on( 'stateChanged', function(){
            // do something
});
```

If you want to detect a specific panel resizing, you can use a [ResizeObserver](https://codepen.io/ryanhagerty/pen/pmLYYW):

```
 let ro = new ResizeObserver( entries => {
 for (let entry of entries) {
           console.log(entry.contentRect.height + ", " + entry.contentRect.width);
           //do something with the height and width of the panel
       }
});

ro.observe(document.querySelector('#panel1'));
```